# CTRL+Space (Edit.CompleteWord) not working with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Since I installed VS2015 Professional, VS's IntelliSense function **Edit.CompleteWord** seems not to work anymore.

So, if I have some unfinished code like `Math.Rou` (which should be `Math.Round();`) and put the cursor on it and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, Visual Studio will not complete the word anymore.

**Some facts which might prevent some additional comments:**

- it worked on my machine with VS2012 & VS2013 before I installed VS2015
- the feature is now disabled on VS2012 and VS2013 as well
- a colleague of mine has excatly the same issues since he installed VS2015
- another colleague did not install VS2015 yet and his older VS-versions are still able to do the auto-complete.
- the function is disabled for C# and VB.NET (I did not test any other languages)
- it is no shortcut problem. Invoking this function from the main menu won't work as well (the shortcut is pretty weird as well but doesn't work either)

[image]

---

**EDIT:** I opened an issue for this bug on Microsoft Connect:

- [CTRL+Space (Edit.CompleteWord) not working with Visual Studio
  2015](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1768923)

Please give it a vote to get it reviewed by Microsoft.

Comment: I encounter that problem occasionally in VS2012 - not sure if it what you are encountering (I don't have VS2015 installed) - but have you tried shutting down all instances of Visual Studio and then re-opening the project?

Comment: It is not occasionally - it does simply not work anymore. Not one single time since I installed VS2015.

Comment: Have you checked Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Intellisense ?

Comment: Yes, I did after I encountered the problem the first time. Everything looking fine.

Comment: I don't know about putting the "();" of the Math.Round example, but to complete the word I've only known to use the Tab key.

Comment: It's not about the "();" this was just to show the whole line. To complete the word with Tab, the Intellisense dropdown has to be open. But without the dropdown, you can usually just use CTRL+Space and VS does the auto-completion or (if the word is not unique) shows the mentioned dropdown.

Comment: The Microsoft Connect link returns a 404.

Comment: I had the problem with the 404 as well but it seems to be working again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok guys, time to face the bitter truth: It seems just to be a problem with an extension I installed weeks ago:

- https://github.com/jbevain/EmojiVS

By disabling this extension, Intellisense came back to life.

I'm sorry about this confusion, thanks for your help!

Comment: For others who land here: ReSharper was doing it for me. Within R#'s settings, you can tell it whether or not you want it to override VS's IntelliSense. One option is to use "Custom IntelliSense" and set which languages you want it to override for.  I was using that with VS's IntelliSense in C# and R#'s for C++.  That caused this bug. Switching to just VS or just R# fixes it.  Thanks for helping me find this, @Waescher!

Comment: I've had problems with EmojiVS too. Too bad, it's a cool extension.

Comment: This may have been the problem for others, but I still can't solve it.  I've relied on CTRL + ENTER for years.  Customising keyboard doesn't work, neither did resetting settings.  Weird, and surprisingly annoying!

Answer (score 56):

For everyone using [Microsoft PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) running into this problem. If you have [Peek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/peek) enabled, it can cause it to stop working.

See: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/26304

[image]

Comment: Came here to add the same note - was tearing my hair out before realising the PowerToys update had claimed the shortcut 

Comment: Thank you so much @Zoidbergseasharp, this was driving me insane. How did you discovered this? Is there some trick to view all the active shortcuts to see conflicts?

Comment: PowerToys v0.70.1 fix this issue by limiting the hook to Desktop, Explorer and the Peek window.

Answer (score 12):

1.) Check that the shortcut is still assigned, **ctrl + Q** and then type **keyboard**

[image]

then filter to **Edit.CompleteWord** and make sure that ctrl + space is still in the list of short cuts under **editor**

[image]

if it isn't in the list then go to the **Press shortcut keys** field and press **ctrl + space** and then **Assign**

If it is in the list then go to the Press shortcut keys field and press **ctrl + space** and then check in the **Shortcut currently used by** list

[image]

there is a chance that the shortcut is being used by another command and you can then filter to that command and remove the shortcut to allow the **Edit.CompleteWord** to work again with the shortcut

If this all fails, export all settings (to make sure you have them) and reset all your settings to the defaults to see if it works. You can then use something like Beyond Compare to try spot what the differences are between your settings to make it work with your previous settings.

Comment: I checked this, of course. It is assigned, but the command won't work even if I use it from the main menu.

Comment: ah, ok. probably try the export and import settings that I just added otherwise I'm not sure what other options you will have

Comment: I disabled all the extensions and enabled just those that I really needed and that fixed the issue. I believe the issue was being caused by one of the extensions.

Answer (score 4):

For me, all I had to do was close the solution and re-open it - this was for an existing older VS solution that I had opened for the first time in VS 2015 Community.

I tried reassigning keys but this did nothing.

Comment: Same problem with VS 2017 Community: solution reopening helps